# Как лучше интегрировать в WordPress вот такой блок информации?

Tags: wordpress, html5, вёрстка, cms, адаптивная-верстка

Для интеграции в WordPress, как будет лучше сверстать во всплывающем окне такое дополнительное меню: каждой категории слева соответствует определенный блок с информацией справа.

И каким образом интегрировать это в WordPress, чтобы иметь возможность полностью управлять меню, добавлять, удалять пункты, менять их местами, иметь возможность изменять информацию правого блока? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте страницу с нужным контентом (меню ресторана в вашем примере) встроенными средствами WordPress или каким-нибудь визуальным редактором, например, Visual Composer. Установите странице видимость "Личное", чтобы избежать прямого доступа к ней.

Добавьте такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
// Add shortcode to output html block from page containing template
function html_block_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $p = get_page_by_title( $atts['title'] );
    if ( empty( $p ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $p->ID, 'post' );
    $p = get_post( $id );

    return do_shortcode( $p->post_content );
}
add_shortcode('block', 'html_block_shortcode');
```

У вас появился шорткод для вывода любой страницы по её заголовку, например:

```
[block title="My Popup"]
```

Такой шорткод выведет содержимое страницы с заголовком "My Popup" (даже если её видимость - "Личное").

В коде выше есть фильтр `wpml_object_id` - он выведет страницу с переводом при использовании плагина WPML и ничего не сделает при его отсутствии. Можете смело оставить в своём коде.

Установите плагин [Easy FancyBox](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/).

На той странице, где надо разместить ссылку на всплывающее окно, добавьте в админке в самый низ заготовку под окно:

```
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
  <div id="my_popup">[block title="My Popup"]</div>
</div>
```

или, если у вас шаблон страницы на php, добавьте в него

```
<div class="fancybox-hidden" style="display: none;">
    <div id="my_popup"><?php echo do_shortcode('[block title="My Popup"]');?></div>
</div>
```

В том месте страницы, где надо сделать вызов всплывающего окна, вставьте ссылку такого вида:

```
<a class="fancybox-inline" href="#my_popup">Кликните для просмотра меню</a>
```

Обратите внимание, что ссылка и заготовка под окно завязаны через id="my_popup" и href="#my_popup".

Таким образом у вас получится полностью редактируемый текст (меню ресторана) во всплывающем окне.